# Accessing class instance variable fails intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm working on a Rails engine and a host application simultaneously. I'm trying to provide a way for the host application to supply code blocks to one of the engine's controllers, which it will call at specific times.

The host application has a `config/initializers` file containing this:

```
MyEngine::TheController.add_doc_hook(:some_key) do
  # Some code to execute
end
```

...and in the engine's controller, I call a specific hook (if it's supplied) like this:

```
def update
  # some code...

  run_doc_hook(:some_key)

  # more code...
end
```

Here are the accessor methods in the engine's controller:

```
# Getter for the blocks - usually returns correctly but sometimes returns nil
def self.doc_hooks
  @doc_hooks
end

# Setter - called by the host application
def self.add_doc_hook(name, &block)
  @doc_hooks ||= {}
  @doc_hooks[name] = block
end
```

And here's the method to run a given hook:

```
protected

# Run pre-set hooks, which can be specified by the host application
def run_doc_hook(name, *args)
  hooks = self.class.doc_hooks # HERE - this is sometimes nil
  if hooks && hooks.has_key?(name) && hooks[name].respond_to?(:call)
    hooks[name].call(*args)
  end
end
```

As you can see, I save the supplied code blocks in a class instance variable. Accessing them works fine maybe 4 out of 5 requests, but **intermittently fails**: the accessor returns `nil`. I can't figure out why this is.

Can anybody see what the problem may be?